# What is an array of split values equal to in Java?

Tags: java, string, split

Trying to split a string of space separated integers in java. To save time not converting the values to integers I wanted to do splitIntegers[i] == splitIntegers[i + 1]. However, I was unable to get any == to come out true even using splitIntegers[i] == "6", since 6 is the first integer stored in the array.

```java
String sixString = "6 6 6";
String[] contains6 = sixString.split(" ");
boolean isSix = contains6[0] == contains6[1]; // is false was expecting true since should both be "6" and if I convert them to integers the values are allowed to be equal
boolean isSixString = contains6[0] == "6"; // is false
boolean areSixes = "6" == "6"; // is true, and can store "6" in a variable and get true
```

So something weird happens when you split a string in Java.

I am translating my knowledge of javaScript where my attempted solution works. Somehow I have an array of strings of 6 that do not equal a string litteral "6" or each other.

I am passing half the tests, and am sure I could speed things up If I did not have to convert the values I split into integers.

Comment: Are you asking [how to compare String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)?

Comment: Arrays don't have a value-based equals method. There's a method to do that instead: `Arrays.equals`

Comment: *"I am translating my knowledge of javaScript"* - despite the similar names the two languages are vastly different, so you should ignore your knowledge of JS when working in Java

Answer (score 1):

`boolean isSix = contains6[0] == contains6[1];`

> Is false was expecting true since should both be "6" and if I convert them to integers the values are allowed to be equal.

If you convert them to `ints` they will be equal because that is how you compare primitives.

If they are Objects they must be compared with `equals`.  In the case  of `"6"` they would be strings.

If the objects are Integers (not ints) then they may be compared using == depending on how they were allocated or assigned since Integer's cache values between `-127 and 128` inclusive.  However, in that case you are only comparing references, not the actual values.

Best practice is to compare Objects using `equals` and primitives using `==`.